# GridView / CardView on click open new activity

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, kotlin

My problem is that i cant manage to start new activity when clicking on `CardView`

**GOAL:** After clicking on the CardView, new activity should start.

I searched the forum and implemented different combinations with `CardView`/`GridView` but nothing works..

How to do it?

i have all in the LinearLayout

**XML Code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Restaurant Menu"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<GridLayout
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:padding="14dp">


    <!-- Row 1 -->

    <!--Column 1 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/drinki"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Drinki i Koktaile"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!--Column 2 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/piwo"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Schłodzone Piwa"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <!-- Row 2 -->

    <!--Column 3 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/wino"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Wytrawne Wina"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!--Column 4 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/sok"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Tłoczone soki"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Row 3 -->

    <!--Column 5 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/gazowane"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Napoje Gazowane"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!--Column 6 -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/cieplo"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Gorące Napoje"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Share us your code please.

Comment: Where the click handling happens?:)

Comment: @FlyingNades In my code there is nothing written yet, because I do not know how to specify onClick in CardView

Comment: @FlyingNades Stantard Kotlin Code on Create Project

Comment: `view.setOnClickListener({ v -> toast("Instead of Toast, Open Activity Here") })`